# Surface book 2 update, bitlocker activated. Did not set a code.

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have a new surface book 2 and was in the middle of setting it up. Did nothing noteworthy except activate hyper-v and WSL. Then an update was scheduled and in the reboot it seems bitlocker has been activated. I did not set a passcode, but it's asking for "Enter the recovery key for this drive" because "the Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed".

I have tried the pin code, but that is not it. What are my options?

Comment: Surface devices come with Device Encryption enabled by default.  If you linked your local account to your Microsoft Account, your recovery key was automatically backed up.  When you enabled Hyper-V you changed your boot configurations thus triggering the prompt you now received.  Device Encryption and BitLocker are two different features by the way.  BitLocker cannot be enabled or disabled automatically, but in the most recent feature updates, it can be suspended in order to install a feature update.

Comment: @Ramhound my account was not linked yet and I do not have the code

Comment: Then your data cannot be recovered since it indeed sounds like, that full disk encryption was enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detach the screen and turn it on. You'll skip the Bitlocker screen and boot into Windows. From there I suggest you take a backup of everything while you can and try linking your Microsoft account to your Surface Book and get the recovery key that way.

If you successfully get the recovery key, turn off the system, attach the screen and keyboard and turn it on again. You'll be prompted with a slightly different looking Bitlocker screen, and once you enter your recovery key your Surface Book is back to normal.

Comment: I like to add that when I detached the screen *the update continued*. 30 minutes after that, my surface book installed what appears to be the "spring update"

Answer (score 1):

The following solution appears in one of Microsoft forums

"BitLocker Issue after Updates Surface Book 2"

...there is a "solution" or better, a "workaround". If you detach the screen before powering up the device, you can actually boot the tablet. And then once it did boot, you can put it back onto the keyboard to use it as a laptop.